# Retornar quantidade de respostas Array PHP

Tags: php, array

Possuo o seguinte array():

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [men_id] => 3
            [usu_id] => 2
            [usu_destino] => 2
            [id_resposta] => 0
            [usu_respondeu] => 0
            [set_assunto] => 147
            [men_mensagem] => Tese 03
            [men_data] => 2017-11-05 16:02:39
            [men_data_lida] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [men_resposta] => 1
            [men_status] => 1
            [total_respostas] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [men_id] => 21
            [usu_id] => 2
            [usu_destino] => 3
            [id_resposta] => 0
            [usu_respondeu] => 0
            [set_assunto] => 147
            [men_mensagem] => Teste de Envio de Mensagem
            [men_data] => 2017-11-05 19:30:38
            [men_data_lida] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [men_resposta] => 1
            [men_status] => 1
            [total_respostas] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [men_id] => 22
            [usu_id] => 2
            [usu_destino] => 2
            [id_resposta] => 0
            [usu_respondeu] => 0
            [set_assunto] => 147
            [men_mensagem] => Apenas enviar um email para o dom Jose da Silva, josedasilvadom@yahoo.com.br
            [men_data] => 2017-11-05 19:31:43
            [men_data_lida] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [men_resposta] => 1
            [men_status] => 1
            [total_respostas] => 1
        )

)
```

Eu preciso retornar um count() de todos os que estiverem com total_resposta = 0.
Como eu posso fazer?

Comment: André o stdClass é uma classe? O que ela faz?

Comment: É retorno do banco de dados... preciso contar todos os que estiverem com total_respostas = 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro deve filtrar os itens do `array` para trazer somente o que precisa que no seu caso em especifico é `total_respostas == 0` depois utilize o `count` para contar a quantidade retornada, ***exemplo***:

```
$total = count(array_filter($array, function($q){
    return $q->total_respostas == 0;
}));
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)
- [count](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php)